# Critical File detected by wordfence .pid

Tags: web

I have Wordfence plugin in my website and it detected as critical a file .pid that I don’t know what it is. How can I find out if this file is malicious or if it was a plug-in that put it there? Do you know if I can delete it? My website was working, then, almost disappear from Google totally. But at the same time I found out spam links that they sent me and I sent disavow. My website suffered many attacks, that is why I am asking. But my question is what should I do about this .pid file?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJDdm.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K379Z.jpg)

To solve this problem, I talked to the server that did not help actually.

Answer (score 0):

The pid files contains the process id (a number) of a given program. This file is often used for ensuring that a particular service or daemon doesn't start multiple instances of itself.

**Is It Dangerous to Leave It There?**
While a .pid file itself isn't dangerous, it could potentially be used in specific scenarios to infer system information or in very targeted attacks. However, this is quite rare but possible in your situation.

**Can You Delete It Safely?**
Deleting a .pid file while the associated process is still running is generally safe in terms of not directly affecting the process's operation. But that probably won't solve anything in your case.

I, personnaly, would check the content of the file, check the process running it and decide what to do from there. Clean your Wordpress, remove any unused plugins and update them.

You expect your website to be attacked and it suffered many. Speak about that to your hosting if they can help you or start fresh.